# What is the meaning of, “…a man who had no truck with looking back..”?

Tags: meaning, american-english

What is the AMERICAN meaning of, “…a man who had no truck with looking back..”?  I understand the meaning of a man in a truck looking back, but “who had no truck with looking back” eludes me.  Alternative meanings for “truck” in Merriam-Webster include “barter” and “swap.”

The sentence, with regard to the Met Gala, appeared in the New York Times on 05/02/2023:

> But Mr. Lagerfeld, who attended the party seven times and was a co-host once, in 2005 when the subject was Chanel, was also *a man who had no truck with looking back*, and who once announced, “I don’t want to see all those old dresses” when asked about an earlier retrospective of his work. And this was a gala full of old dresses. (A positive change, for once, from all the one-offs of the past.)

Edited for clarity, as requested; as it pertains to American English only.  I neither write nor read French.  I thought the Cambridge Dictionary was for British words.  I was using MW Dictionary, for American words.  I apologize.

Comment: The American and British meanings are the same: to have truck with something = to have dealings with something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you say that you will *have no truck with* something, you are refusing to be involved with it in any way.
[Origin of the phrase "Have no truck with"](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/have-no-truck-with.html)

In other words, Karl Lagerfeld doesn't want to think about the past.

Comment: This answer gives concise meaning and good etymological reason. It should be accepted. Perhaps it should give a quote from the quoted link to make that clearer to readers.

Answer (score 8):

The idiom **to have no truck with something/someone** means, [according to Cambridge:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/truck)

> to refuse to become involved with something or someone because you do not approve of it, him, or her

Comment: I see a loose connection between this use of no truck, and no traction.

Comment: @anton "troque", not "truque"

Comment: @YosefBaskin Indeed, there is none. Graffito gives you the correct associations with words such as French “troque”.